# C# Windows Application using WebSocket for streaming image

Tags: c#, video, bitmap, websocket, esp8266

I have a camera (now using Arducam OV2640) connected to ESP8266. I am trying to build something that sends websocket data between a C# application and ESP8266. The main purpose of this project is to build a robot, that can view the camera on the robot and control it using a C# application via Websocket. 
However, the progress of my project is that it is able to send the command to the robot to make it move, but upon receiving the data from ESP8266, I am not able to piece the data into a proper video streaming to view on the windows C# application. I have used C# bitmap library but not able work properly. Any help is much appreciated. Below is what I have done so far:

```
    //to send the data to ESP8266 Wifi board
    public async void webSocketOperation(String operation)
    {
        ArraySegment<byte> bytesToSend = new ArraySegment<byte>(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(operation));
        await UserInterface.ws.SendAsync(
            bytesToSend, WebSocketMessageType.Text,
            true, CancellationToken.None);
    }

    //to receive the data sent from ESP8266 board
    public async Task receiveData()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[819200]);             

            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
            pbVideoFeed.Image = BytesToBitmap(buffer);
            if (ws.State != WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //to convert from bytes to image
    private Bitmap BytesToBitmap(ArraySegment<byte> buffer)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = null;
        byte[] image_data = new byte[409600];
        Bitmap resize_img = new Bitmap(pbVideoFeed.Width, pbVideoFeed.Height);
        Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(resize_img);

        image_data = buffer.ToArray();
        try
        {
            stream = new MemoryStream(image_data);
            Bitmap result = new Bitmap(stream);
            graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
            graphic.DrawImage(result, new Rectangle(0, 0, pbVideoFeed.Width, pbVideoFeed.Height));

            graphic.Dispose();

            return new Bitmap((Image)resize_img);
            //return new Bitmap((Image)new Bitmap(stream));
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In which format you are getting your imagefile , does your Camera having any streaming IP address.

Comment: If you are able to access your images in webbrowser. . then look for ffmpeg. . it's great tool for converting images to video stream . .

Comment: @csharpcoder Hi, Yes. There is a IP address assigned to ESP8266 wifi board. Both the ESP8266 and computer needs to connect to the same subnet to communicate. I have programmed the esp8266 to connect to the wifi once it is powered up.

Comment: Then you should be getting a stream of image from it . in mpeg format , you can convert it to a video using ffmpeg .

Comment: @csharpcoder sure! i will read up on ffmpeg and try to apply it on C# windows application. Thank you for the help!